# Reading complex number from a csv file using python

Tags: python, numpy

I try to make ML program but ı face to problem reading complex data from my csv extension dataset

```
   from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt
   import numpy as np
   from keras.models import Sequential
   from keras.layers import Dense
   # load the dataset
   dataset = genfromtxt("C:/Users/username/Desktop/dataset/snr_10_tau_09/clear.csv", dtype=complex 
   ,delimiter=",")
   # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
   print(dataset[:])
```

And my output is

```
[[ 1.+0.j  1.+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j  1.+0.j]
[ 1.+0.j  1.+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j  1.+0.j]
[ 1.+0.j  1.+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j  1.+0.j]
...
[nan+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j nan+0.j]]
```

And example of my data's first raw :

```
1,1,-0.0681107934958098 - 0.321707498751689j,0.000400898877777433 + 
0.00114494815465579j,1.14287673226517 - 0.0363472573808049j,1
```

I did not understand where is my mistake, in my data or my code?
When ı try to print my data,it shown  "nan+0.j"
I cannot fix this part properly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify converters for all of your columns (there are 6 columns, so you'll need that many converter functions):

```py
np.genfromtxt(
    your_file_name, 
    delimiter=',', 
    dtype=np.complex, 
    converters={k: lambda x: np.complex(x.replace(b' ', b'').decode()) for k in range(5)}
)

array([  1.00000000e+00+0.j        ,   1.00000000e+00+0.j        ,
        -6.81107935e-02-0.3217075j ,   4.00898878e-04+0.00114495j,
         1.14287673e+00-0.03634726j,   1.00000000e+00+0.j        ])
```

Comment: Thats mean is error come from blank between number and calculation operant like   "2  +  3j" is wrong and "2+3j" true.Do ı got it correctly?And  thank you ı chance blank as searching and replacing in my dataset using excel.Than my code show data correctly.Hence,I did not need  to make any changing on my code.